# Is this circuit for Piezo Transducer sufficient?

Tags: audio

I want to drive this Piezo Transducer (https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/670/cpt-9019s-smt-1310960.pdf) directly from a pin on my STM32F0 microcontroller. I don't want to use a BJT transistor because the max current consumption of the transducer is so low (5mA). Right now I have the following schematic.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQfJJX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The pin on the STM32F0 can source a max of 3.3V (peak-to-peak). Since the max current consumption of the transducer is 5mA, I want to limit the current going into it to 2.5mA to be on the safe side. Using Ohm's Law, I get a resistance value of R = \$\frac{V}{I}\$ = \$\frac{3.3V}{0.0025A}\$ = 1320\$\Omega\$

Is this circuit correct or am I missing something fundamentally?

Comment: you are assuming that the transducer has no resistance ... why don't you read the datasheet  to determine the maximum voltage that you can apply to the transducer

Comment: Am i misinterpreting max current consumption? My understanding is that I should not feed more than 5mA of current into the transducer.

Comment: 720 ohm, since the transducer has 600.

Comment: yes, you are thinking that somehow you can push more than 5mA without increasing the voltage ...

Comment: think about a water tap in your kitchen ... the water pressure in the supply pipe is like voltage ... partially open tap is like a resistor ... it allows only a small amount of water current to pass .... you cannot get more flow unless you increase the pressure or decrease the resistance

Answer (score 0):

The spec should be read that if you apply a 4 kHz square wave at 3 Vp-p, the transducer will draw less than 5 mA.  The transducer will take up to 25 V, so no worries about overdriving it.

The load on your processor will look like a capacitor rather than a resistor, somewhere around 12 nF.  So if you want to limit the current, it will depend on the operating frequency you choose.

Good luck!