# Is this circuit for Piezo Transducer and corresponding resistor values correct?

Tags: resistors, audio, stm32, schematics

I want to drive this piezo transducer (https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/670/cpt-9019s-smt-1310960.pdf) at 3V and 4kHz with STM32F0 microcontroller. This is a follow-up to my previous question ([Is this circuit for Piezo Transducer sufficient?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/458458/is-this-circuit-for-piezo-transducer-sufficient?noredirect=1#comment1153263_458458)). Since then, I've made some progress and come up with this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXZLYD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R1 is to limit the amount of current the microcontroller pin draws and R2 is to discharge the speaker when there is no output to the speaker (since it acts like a capacitor). The MCU can draw a max of 25mA of current, but the speaker only uses a max of 5mA when driven at 3V and 4kHz. So I will limit the current draw from the MCU to 10mA. This gives i_c a value of 10mA and R1 a value of \$330\Omega\$.  (R1 = \$\frac{3.3V}{10mA}\$). Since the speaker draws a max of 5mA, i_s = 5mA and i_b = 5mA. The schematic with the values plugged in is:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOJDdw.png)</sup>

To determine R2, I know I want 3V to be applied to the speaker, so the voltage drop over R2 will be 3V. Using Ohm's Law, \$R2 = \frac{3V}{5mA} = 600\Omega\$.

My two main questions are:

1. Is this circuit fundamentally correct to drive the transducer?
2. Do the values for resistors R1 and R2 make sense or am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the piezo speaker only draws 5 mA at 4 kHz when driven with a peak positive voltage of 3 volts then there is no need for a current limiting resistor if you are driving it with a peak voltage of 3 volts.

On the other hand, it might be a good idea to have a series resistor to prevent the instantaneous current draw from the MCU pin exceeding limits stated in the data sheet so, focus on that and not the speaker.

You don’t need a parallel resistor to discharge the piezo speaker capacitance because when the MCU pin cycles naturally through a low part of the waveform, it will discharge the piezo capacitance.

Your calculation for R2 is fundamentally misplaced in theory.